# Google Mock, argument matcher using another argument

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googlemock

Is there any convenient way to match one argument against another one (which is a wildcard)? For example:

```
ON_CALL(calculator_mock, division(_, SameAsArgument<0>).WillByDefault(Return(1.0))
```

Is there such matcher like SameAsArgument ?

UPDATE: maybe `SameAsArgument<N>` is not very good. What I need is a matcher `Argument<N>`, which will get the value of N-th argument.

Thanks!

Comment: what is it supposed to do?

Comment: For calculator_mock.division(x, x) should return 1.0. (first argument is this same as the second one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that can be done like explained in the ["Matching Multiple Arguments as a Whole"](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#matching-multiple-arguments-as-a-whole) chapter of their cookbook.

In your case, should be :

```
EXPECT_CALL(calculator_mock, division(_,_))
      .With(AllOf(Args<0, 1>(Eq())));
```

Comment: moved to here: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#matching-multiple-arguments-as-a-whole